# Computing a determinant of order $2d$

Tags: matrices, determinant

We define a square matrix $M$ with $2d$ rows and columns with components in this form

$$M_{i,2j-1}=\left\{\begin{array}\\1 \; \text{if}\; i=2j\\
-1 \; \text{if}\; i=3j+1\\
0 \; \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$
and
$$M_{i,2j}=\left\{\begin{array}\\1 \; \text{if}\; i=2j-1\\
-1 \; \text{if}\; i=j-1\\
0 \; \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

The question is to prove that $\det(M)=(-1)^d$.

I don't have any idea how I can find the result. What I have do so far: I created a MATLAB function and  I verified numerically the equality with $d$ up to 1000. How we can prove it?